# Value from one command as parameter to another command

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to figure out how to get a value from one command as a parameter to another command, and use the output of both in a single table.  Specifically I am using two cmdlets, `Get-Mailbox` and `Get-MailboxStatistics` (this is against an Exchange 2010 server).

From `Get-Mailbox` I need the `DisplayName`, `UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults` and Database fields.  Added to this, I need to get from `Get-MailboxStatistics` the `TotalItemSize` and `StorageLimitStatus` fields.

I can run each of these commands individually, but cannot figure out how to use the `DisplayName` value from `Get-Mailbox` fed into the Identity value for `Get-MailboxStatistics` command and then output the whole lot into a single table.

I was trying something along these lines:

```
get-mailbox | ForEach-Object {write-host $_.DisplayName, $_.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults, $_.Database, Get-MailboxStatistics $_.SamAccountName}
```

Instead of actually processing the `Get-MailboxStatistics` as a command it just display it as text.  How can I get PS to treat this as a command and not text for the `write-host` cmdlet?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use parentheses, something along these lines:

```
get-mailbox | ForEach-Object { Write-Host ` 
    $_.DisplayName, `
    $_.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults, `
    $_.Database, `
    (Get-MailboxStatistics $.SamAccountName) }
#   ^------- note the parentheses ---------^
```

Comment: I wish that would work, as it appears to make sense and I can understand it.  However PS just gives me this error:

Pipeline not executed because a pipeline is already executing. Pipelines cannot be executed concurrently.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Microsoft.Power...tHelperRunspace:ExecutionCmdletHelperRunspace) [],
   PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemotePipelineExecutionFailed

Answer (score 1):

Using bits of info from the previous answers, combined with some Google searching and more than my fair share of cursing, came up with the following script that actually works:

```
$mbx = Get-Mailbox

ForEach ($cur in $mbx)
{
  $stat = (Get-MailboxStatistics $cur.DisplayName)

  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    DisplayName = $cur.DisplayName
    UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults = $cur.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults
    SamAccountName = $cur.SamAccountName
    StorageLimitStatus = $stat.StorageLimitStatus
    TotalItemSize = $stat.TotalItemSize
    Database = $stat.Database
  }

}
```

thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all mailboxes, for each one assign its statistics to a variable, then create a custom object with properties from both objects:

```
Get-Mailbox | ForEach-Object {

    $stats = $_ | Get-MailboxStatistics

    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
        UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults = $_.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults
        Database = $_.Database
        SamAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
        TotalItemSize  = $stats.TotalItemSize
        StorageLimitStatus = $stats.StorageLimitStatus
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I put this into a script and tried to run it.  The entries from Get-Mailbox are showing up just fine, but others are blank and PS gives me a pipeline error:

Pipeline not executed because a pipeline is already executing. Pipelines cannot be executed concurrently.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Microsoft.Power...tHelperRunspace:ExecutionCmdletHelperRunspace) [],
   PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemotePipelineExecutionFailed